# How to manage image with different dimensions which i take from user in same card?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, django-templates

Images comes from the database which a user posted but the problem here images are with different dimensions within the card card.

[image]

If we fix the height and width pic does not remain in its original ratio.

[image]

But i want picture remain in original form but its height or width may change within the card like

[image]

```
{% for post in show_posts %} 
   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
      <div class="card listing-preview">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.photo.url }}" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
       <div class="listing-heading text-center">
        <h4 class="text-primary">{{ person.name }}</h4>
       </div>
       <hr>
      <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
           <div class="col-12">
             City: {{ post.city }}</div>
           </div>
      <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
           <div class="col-12">
                 Area: {{ post.area }}</div>
             </div>
             <hr>
             <div class="row text-secondary pb-2">
               <div class="col-12">
                 <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ person.list_date timesince }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the maximum height of `card-img-top`.

> The max-height CSS property sets the maximum height of an element. It
> prevents the used value of the height property from becoming larger
> than the value specified for max-height. - [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)

```
.card-img-top {
   max-height: 300px;
   width: auto;
}
```

Comment: by applying this same problem came i shown in image 1

Answer (score -1):

for example if you wont all images would same size, you should `.card{ height:300px; width:300px; }`

```
.card img{width:100%; object-fit: contain;}
```

Comment: Using fixed size is a bad solution.